# Entity Framework Query against NonMapped property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Domain Model:

```
public class Media : Entity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public int LevenshteinScore { get; set; }
}
```

Service:

```
public ICollection<T> GetSearchedMedias(string searchString)
{
    var searchables = _repository.GetAll();

    foreach (var searchable in searchables)
    {
        var score = Levenshtein.iLD(searchable.Name, searchString);

        searchable.LevenshteinScore = score;
    }

    return searchables.Where(x => x.LevenshteinScore <= 30).ToList();
}
```

I get the error:

> The specified type member 'LevenshteinScore' is not supported in LINQ to Entities.

Obviously this is because it has the attribute NotMapped. 
Calling `ToList()` would work but also loads unnecessary data into memory which I don't need.

```
searchables.ToList().Where(x => x.LevenshteinScore <= 30).ToList();
```

Is there a way I can use my non-mapped property in my query for the database execution?

Comment: Is `searchables` of type `Media`?

Comment: It is of type media, yes.

Comment: *Calling `ToList()` would work but also loads unnecessary data into memory which I don't need.* Your `foreach` already does that. And you are trying to run the db query a second time, which make no sense. Finally, there is no way to use NotMapped property in LINQ to Entities query.

Comment: @IvanStoev You are correct. Thanks.